# How to connect room in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm fallowing `socket.io` [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) for create a chat with Room system, but when I execute fallowing code in client side, it returning "undefined"

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event'); // this will returning "undefined"
```

Because `io` not has function `to()`

Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you never joined the room. The documentation gives this code *right before* the code you have in your question:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

Another this is that code shouldn't return any value (as far as I'm aware of), so with no return value it would return *undefined*.

Edit: to switch, you use this syntax:

```
socket.leave('some room');
socket.join('another room');
```

Comment: But after joined the room, is possible send message desalinated for any room, not global?

Comment: @Lai32290 do you mean broadcast to all rooms or do you mean switch rooms?

Comment: @Lai32290 that's in the documentation, although I updated my answer.

Comment: So when client send messages, everybody in global room and "another room" will receive it?

Comment: @Lai32290 I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the global room... I think it just sends the message to the current room only.